# What are the colours of Lisa's jewelry in portrait room?

Tags: resident-evil-2002

One of the puzzles in the Resident Evil Remake involves a room full of portraits, including one of a woman (Lisa), wearing three kinds of jewelry: a crown, necklace, and bracelet.

[image: original photo]

Their's also three other coloured portraits in the room, with each one corresponding to one of the aforementioned jewelry. The goal of the puzzle is to shine coloured lights on each of these portraits so that the colours of the portraits line up with the colour of their corresponding piece of jewelry.

[image: photo after shining green light]

This is all well and good, except for the fact that I'm colour blind, and so I really have no idea what colours the crown and bracelet are, because they just look way to similar to me. This wouldn't be such a big deal, except if you mess up the puzzle, a flock of crows hanging out in the room decide to attack you. Due to this, using trial and error on the puzzle isn't exactly ideal.

What are the colours of the crown, necklace, and bracelet that the woman in this portrait is wearing?

Comment: Posting this since every time I play through this game, this puzzle is always annoying to deal with, and I figure my fellow colour blind gamers playing through will appreciate it as well.

Comment: How do colour-blind people recognize what colour the portraits are?

Comment: @Mast It actually tells you via text, as you can see in my second picture.

Comment: I thought that would only happen *after* you've tried. Considering trial-and-error wasn't an option, thought that wouldn't be of help then either.

Comment: @Mast It tells you the colour before you change the colour of a portrait. More importantly, though, is you need to first press a switch on Lisa before the puzzle is either solved, or the crows attack you. It's when you press that switch the game checks the colours of each portrait, and activates the crows if they're wrong.

Comment: Ah, it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: This puzzle literally looks like a puzzle that is only a puzzle if you're colour blind, which makes me wonder what's the point of including it...

Comment: Wow... this truly is a big accessibility fail.

Comment: As a game dev, thank you for calling this out. We need to be aware of this kind of thing.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure this out themselves on a future occasion, it is actually possible for a colorblind person to determine the names of the colors using only the screenshot above and the internet.

If you open the image in an editor, such as the *GNU Image Manipulation Program* (GIMP), you will most likely find a *color picker* tool. Using this tool it is possible to extract the numerical color value of a pixel in the screenshot. Taking a value just from the center of the necklace yields the color:

#### **#c163d3**

this value is not immediately helpful, but there exist websites, such as colorhexa.com, that will give semantic information about that specific color. For example, the page https://www.colorhexa.com/c163d3 describes the color we picked from the image as a "**Moderate magenta**"

we can do the same for the other pieces of jewelry and get the following:

```
crown:     55b15a  =  Dark moderate lime green
bracelet:  e0996f  =  Soft orange
necklace:  c163d3  =  Moderate magenta
```

This technique can be further refined by taking the average of an area of color values to avoid falling for local highlights or shadows, but in this case the simple approach would be enough to get a sufficiently clear idea of the colors to be able to solve the puzzle.

Comment: _Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime._

Comment: @Bernat "Teach a  man to see" might be more accurate ;)

Comment: despite the fact that I've spent years helping people on stackoverflow, this is after a single day my most well-received answer on the entire stackexchange network. go figure.

Comment: I'd be cautious with that site. It says 008000 is "dark lime green" while I wouldn't say it's lime green at all; more like forest green. Likewise, it says 000001 is "very dark blue" despite the fact that it's indistinguishable from black without a side-by-side comparison.

Comment: @MooseBoys Good point. To Andreas, I'd suggest that site is a nice guide, but largely an unnecessary extra step that might muddy the waters in some cases. Most color pickers will tell you explicitly the makeup of the color in terms of its red, green, and blue components. Unless you're dealing with subtle differences in tints, it will often be enough to know that a color with red/green/blue values of e.g. 10/200/50 is _mostly_ green or, as in the example given (193/99/211), _mostly_ blue and red (which combine to make purple).

Answer (score 46):

The colours of the jewelry are:

- Crown is green
- Necklace is purple
- Bracelet is orange

Answer (score 29):

If you have a smartphone or similar device, my recommendation would be to install a [color picker/detector app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=color%20detector%20picker&c=apps) that can use the camera. You can then start the app, point it to the relevant section on your screen and it will show you the color, in many cases including a *color name:*

[image: Screenshot of color detector, pointed at screen with picture]

In this case, I pointed my smartphone at the screen with your question.

(FYI, I read about people with color blindness that also use tools like these to pick their clothes!)

Comment: It's funny because I'm colourblind and it never occured to me that the colours of my clothes may be off.

Comment: +1 This is really helpful for when playing a console game

Comment: @MechMK1 I’m not colorblind, and it still doesn’t occur to me that the colors of my clothes may be off.

Comment: @MechMK1, bad clothing colour choice is very significant in the history of the study of colour blindness. Dalton was motivated to investigate it after accidentally buying red underwear for his mother.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have to admit, I only noticed I was color blind because I kept referring to one of my clothes as "green", although for others it was clearly brown.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Someone on quora said the same thing (about the underwear), but according to the BMJ they were stockings: https://jmg.bmj.com/content/jmedgenet/25/6/422.full.pdf (p 424). His mother is quoted: "I can never show myself ... in them" - which would only make sense if they were outer garments.